# Connecting VS Code to Enterprise Bitbucket repo using personal access tokens or ssh keys instead of logging in

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket, ssh-keys

More or less all in the title,

My company has a custom Bitbucket project set up through Atlassian that we want to connect to our VS Code IDEs. When doing the tutorial in the Atlassian Bitbucket/Jira extension for VS code it asks for the repo's URL and our username and password. For security reasons we don't want to do that. On the [Atlassian website outlining connecting VS Code to Bitbucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-vs-code/) makes reference to using a [personal access token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver063/personal-access-tokens-972354166.html) though I haven't found what exactly to do with this?

What we need to know is what to do with a personal access token in VS code once you've created one.  Based on the top point in the personal access token walkthrough it seems like it has something to do with a REST command but I (a REST ignoramus) don't have the faintest on where I'd store the token, command, or how it would pertain to the Atlassian VS Code extension.

Any help is immensely appreciated!

We've gone through the guides posted by Atlassian and linked to from the VS Code extension and have custom tokens and ssh keys associated with each of our accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "though I haven't found what exactly to do with this?"

You simply use it as your password:

```
username / <yourToken>
```

As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667356/connecting-vs-code-to-enterprise-bitbucket-repo-using-personal-access-tokens-or/71672410?noredirect=1#comment132887339_71672410) by [koral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10854888/koral), "`username`" means the actual Bitbucket user name, *not* the literal string '`username`'.

Comment: From experience with setting up SMTP access with `apikey` as username and actual api key as password, I thought `username` meant the string `username`. @VonC meant the actual username. Just in case someone had similar thought :)

Comment: @koral Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my experience with in-house Bitbucket v6.7.5, VonC's suggestion to use token as password yields

```
Authentication error
Error authenticating with Bitbucket: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
```

Comment: Strange, this was [seen before](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9720#issuecomment-566098207), but what cause by a faulty `.env` file.

Comment: [This issue](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlascode/issues/593/bitbucket-authentication-cant-be-saved) does not seem to have a definitive answer.

Comment: I'm surprised that this is still an issue. @VonC: I'm not able to see the issue you linked to for some reason, has there been any progress on it?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha This issue is no longer public, so I cannot check its status either.